Why do Fibonacci sequences result from this process?
If we have two columns of numbers made by the following rule, we get two Fibonacci sequences.
Is there a straightforward way that enables us to just 'see' why this would happen.  If anyone can find one, that would be great.
Alternatively there may be a way to prove it using properties of the golden ratio, since this property was noticed while trying a question about finding but the value of the golden ratio raised to a given power.
The first way is preferable if there is one.  Thankyou.

The $b_n$ are made
by adding the two above and dividing by 2 e.g. $b_4 = 3$ and $b_4 = \frac{a_3+b_3}{2}$
The $a_n$ are made by adding the $a$ to $5$ times the $b$, and dividing by 2 e.g. $a_4 = 7$ and $a_4 = \frac{a_3+5b_3}{2}$

Hint: write the series $a_k$ in the form of $b_k$, and get $b_k+b_{k+1}=b_{k+2}$

The numbers $a_n$ are called the Lucas numbers usually denoted by $L_n$. They follow the same recursion rule as the Fibonacci numbers but with the initial conditions $L_0=2$, $L_1=1$ instead of $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$. Your observations are the well known formulas $5F_n+L_n = 2 L_{n+1}$ and $F_n + L_n = 2 F_{n+1}$ which can be proved by a straightforward induction.

@Leo Ji  Yes, that works, thankyou

@Jjagmath  thanks
